# How do I split characters from a string of varying length in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to split characters from the following string:

> 135/GB 102 Main (DA)/Shelf 1/Rack 1/RckShlf 2/Bx 2/Pos35

```
Sub SplitString()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("N3:N6")
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(6)
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(5)
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(4)
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(3)
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(2)
        Debug.Print Split(c, "/")(1)
    Next c

End Sub
```

Ideally I would like to isolate only the numerical characters between each "/" but it would be a huge time saver just to be able to split all of the characters between "/".

Comment: Have you tried `Text to Columns`?

Comment: or in VBA there's the SPLIT function

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off going through the whole string rather than breaking it into sections and then trying to find the numbers in each section.

Consider the following code:

```
Sub SplitString()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer

    For Each c In Range("N3:N6")
        Dim Section As String

        For Counter = 1 To Len(c)
            Dim s As String

            s = Mid(c, Counter, 1)

            If IsNumeric(s) Then
                Section = Section + s
            ElseIf (s = "/") Then
                Debug.Print Section
                Section = ""
            End If
        Next

        Debug.Print Section
        Section = ""
    Next c
End Sub
```

This will go through your range, and create a string containing all of the numbers in each section, which is will then `Debug.Print` when the section ends (when it finds a `/`).

The output on the above will be:

```
135
102
1
1
2
2
35
```

If you need to go through the string in reverse order then change the counter to run from `Len(c)` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract numbers with regular expression. Since you didn't mention, in which way you need to get the result, I assume this is an array:

```
Function GetNums(s)
    Dim arr(), m, mc, x
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True: .Pattern = "\d+"
        Set mc = .Execute(s)
        If mc.Count > 0 Then
            For Each m In mc
                x = x + 1: ReDim Preserve arr(1 To x)
                arr(x) = m.Value
            Next
        End If
    End With
    GetNums = arr
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim s, z, x
    s = "135/GB 102 Main (DA)/Shelf 1/Rack 1/RckShlf 2/Bx 2/Pos35"
    z = GetNums(s)
    For x = 1 To UBound(z): Debug.Print z(x): Next
End Sub

' Output:
' 102
' 1
' 1
' 2
' 2
' 35
```